# Dynamic updation in Content Management System

Tags: jquery, content-management-system

I have a banner Image with text overlaid. I want the text color to be dynamic so that it is visible on light or dark backgrounds.

How can I achieve that using JQuery?

Which property of the image should I check to apply the conditions?

Comment: can you check by img src?

Comment: @ techLove . Thanks for your reply but I wont be having control over what image Client will use.

Comment: Improved English